# How to obtain a custom local requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to retrieve a `require` function with a custom local context?
Same as requiring a `require` from a module, but i need to arbitrarily choose the base path:
as this pseudo:

```
var custom_local_require = require.local('/base/url/');
custom_local_require('./path/to/module'); // will return module `/base/url/path/to/module.js`
```

[EDIT]
digging in requirejs code i found these
[var ctx = requirejs.s.newContext(contextName);](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L196)
 [ctx.makeRequire(relMap, options);](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1383)

are `requirejs.s.*` *safe* apis ?
any documentation?

meanwhile i ended up with this..

```
function localrequire(baseurl) {
  function path_relative_to(path) {
    if (path.startsWith('.'))
      return baseurl + path;
    else
      return path;
  }
  return function(deps, cb, eb) {
    if (Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(deps)) {
      deps = deps.map(path_relative_to);
      return require(deps, cb, eb);
    } else {
      var _local_path = path_relative_to(deps);
      return require(_local_path);
    }
  }
}
var custom_local_require = localrequire('/base/url/');
custom_local_require('./path/to/module'); // will return module `/base/url/path/to/module.js`
```

seems to work but any suggestion and bug-smell is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
as from docs there is a [Multiversion Support](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion) for the purpose:
just call `require.config` with a `context` property, it returns an *isolated* `require` function with that configuration.
so, to solve my problem:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl:'/mainbase/'
});
var _ctx_config = {
    baseUrl:'/base/url/'
    // any other config may be added here 
    // they will be kept isolated 
};
var custom_local_require = require.config(_ctx_config);
custom_local_require('path/to/module'); // will return module `/base/url/path/to/module.js`    
require('path/to/module'); // will return module `/mainbase/path/to/module.js`
```